# Saving changes very slow via Datacontext

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, datacontext, azure-sql-database

I am working on MVC3 .NET Project with Entity framework and SQL Azure Database.

When i try to save multiple records at once in a table it takes several minutes to finish the operation!

I use the same Datacontext for adding Object and saving changes also i've tried to use multiple Datacontexts but the results are the same.

Comment: It would help if you provided more details. As it stands now, not sure what you expect in terms of an answer. What is "multiple records": 5? 10,000? Where is your code running (emulator? in a datacenter?), and where is your SQL Azure database? If in a datacenter, is it in the same one as your SQL Azure database?

Comment: The number of records is about 15 records !! the code is runing on Windows Azure as a webrole and the database also.

Answer (score 0):

In addition, please check out the following documents:

Entity Framework performance considerations: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc853327.aspx

SQL Azure performance guide: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/sql-azure-performance-and-elasticity-guide.aspx

Best Regards,

Ming Xu.