# Form Authentication / Profiles slow on Azure Cloud, fine locally

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-membership, azure-sql-database

I'm using MVC 4 on Azure, and it loads very slowly (over a minute).  Here are the load times of a few pages:
[image: http://i.imgur.com/V4brS.png]  (the 6.9 minutes was when I tried loading 7 tabs with different pages)

This problem does not occur when I'm using the Azure emulator, locally.

I've tried using an extra large instance, and using remote desktop to run the site locally, and it was just as slow.  Also I have tried using IIS Express and normal IIS, and nothing there either.

I created a completely fresh MVC project using the "Internet application" template, which includes security, and it is very 
slow as well, so I'm pretty sure the other things I'm using in my project are not causing the problem.  Here are the load 
times with just the default MVC project:
[image]

I was originally using separate affinity regions for my membership DB and my website, but I've tried using matching affinity groups on both the blank MVC template with forms authentication and my project.

Revisiting pages doesn't improve their speed significantly.

I also tried creating just a MVC site without authentication, with a 10x5000 table generated:

```
<html>
<body>
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                @for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
                {
                    <th>@i
                    </th>
                }
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @for(int i = 0; i < 5000; i++)
            {
                <tr>
                    @for(int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
                    {
                        <td>Row @i , column @j</td>    
                    }
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

This loads fine, both locally and on the cloud.  Even from a cold start it is only ~10-15 seconds.

So I'm fairly certain that the issue lies in the Profile/Membership/Authentication of ASP.NET, but only while it is deployed 
to Azure (since I'm using the same SQL Azure database with Universal Providers when running locally, and there aren't these 
slowdowns).

I expected this problem to be more common, but the only thing that really seemed relevant was this:
[social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsazuremanagement/thread/7d3323d8-571b-4b8f-9fdb-bd5ccc6c39b7](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsazuremanagement/thread/7d3323d8-571b-4b8f-9fdb-bd5ccc6c39b7)
(possibly this: [stackoverflow.com/questions/10791433/saving-changes-very-slow-via-datacontext](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10791433/saving-changes-very-slow-via-datacontext))

I'm working through the things to try, as suggested in that thread, at: [windowsazure.com/en-us/manage/windows/best-practices/](http://windowsazure.com/en-us/manage/windows/best-practices/)

Comment: I can't think of the reason given what you tried/observed but just to check the obvious: are your affinity group settings for web (if you look at the location on your portal) and your DB Region the same?

Comment: Ahh, good question, forgot to add that.  Originally I was using a DB someone else had set up, in North Central US, and the site that I had set up was using West US.  

I did create a DB on West US when I tried out the blank MVC application w/forms authentication, and tried out both DBs for membership on the test project and on my main project, and neither worked.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked that you've checked "Allow other Windows Azure services to access this server" in the Firewall rules for the database server?

I wonder if the provider is failing to reach the database and retrying before finally timing out (though, to be honest, I'd expect an exception to be thrown).

If you've added a firewall rule for your network, but not added one for Azure itself you might experience such an issue.

Comment: Yes, the databases both allow other Windows Azure services to access them, which I believe is the default.  They also both have firewall exceptions for my local testing, and I've checked to make sure data was actually being written to the DB instead of to some local database file.  

Originally I was suspicious of the 1 minute timeouts and was looking for retry values like that, but I couldn't find anything, and subsequent values ranged from ~30-90 seconds.